# ASPX File only Shows Code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been trying to upload my site to my Hostinger domain for a few days now, however for some reason the .aspx file shows the raw code and doesn't show any of the GUI present when run through the browser.
How would you advise?

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Mater Pages/Primary.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>


<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
<style type="text/css">
 .auto-style1 {
  width: 873px;
  height: 455px;
  }
</style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cpMainContent"   Runat="Server">
<h2 style="text-align: center">
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Hello and   welcome to my personal website. I hope that you enjoy your visit.</h2>
<h3 style="text-align: center">
    If for any reason you can&#39;t find exactly what you are looking for then please use the contact form <a href="Main%20Pages/Contact%20Me.aspx">here</a> and you&#39;ll get a response within 2-3 working days</h3>
<h3 style="text-align: center">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <img alt="" class="auto-style1" src="Images/Default/image%20for%20hompage.png" /></h3>
<p style="text-align: center">
    &nbsp;
    <script async  src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- Website Ad Test -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
 style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
 data-ad-client="ca-pub-8284273019831171"
 data-ad-slot="7241345648"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
</p>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1"   Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Are you sure the hosting account is for .NET? Only servers running IIS can display ASPX files.

Comment: Please check if there is not any problem while calling your master page..

Answer (score 1):

Looking at Hostinger's website it looks to me that they do not support .net framework.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that your server does not execute the code in your .aspx web page, it just returns the content (the source code) of it.

Contact your web server provider and make sure they are serving .NET pages.